Apply different treesiter injections for different filenames
I am using treesitter-go-template with neovim. I have different templates with different syntax and different file extenstions, for example:
section.tmpl.html
{{ define "section" }}
<div>{{ .Text }}</div>
{{ end }}

some-helper.tmpl.ts
{{ define "add-section-ts" }}
export function addSection(parent:  HTMLDivElement): HTMLElement {
  const section = `{{ template "section" . }}`;
  parent.innerHTML += section; 
  return <HTMLElement>(parent.lastElementChild!); }
{{ end }}

Is it possible to apply injection for html only if filename ends with .tmpl.html, and typescript injection only for .tmpl.ts?
((text) @injection.content
 (#set! injection.language "html")
 (#set! injection.combined)
 (#set! injection.include-children))

((text) @injection.content
 (#set! injection.language "typescript")
 (#set! injection.combined)
 (#set! injection.include-children))

